# A counterexample about banach steinhaus theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two banach spaces. $L(X,Y)$ is the set of all bounded linear operators from $X$ into $Y$. $\{T_i \mid i =1,2,...\}$ $\subset$ $L(X,Y)$.

**Could anyone construct an example that when $A = \{x \mid$ $sup\Vert T_i x \Vert ＜\infty \}$ is first class set, $sup \Vert T_i \Vert ＜ \infty$.**

I have known that if $sup \Vert T_i \Vert = \infty$, $A$ must be a first class set(we don't need that $X$ and $Y$ are two banach spaces.) I want to find an example in which $A$ could be a countable set. But this is a little difficult.

Comment: If $S := \sup \lVert T_i\rVert < \infty$, then $\sup \lVert T_i x\rVert \leqslant S\cdot \lVert x\rVert < \infty$ for every $x$.

Comment: Thank you. I have lost the course and forgot the basic definition...